# How to pass data from a Symfony controller to a Vue 3 component using Vite and Twig?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony, twig

I'm working on a full-stack application that uses Symfony 5.4 with Twig as the template engine, and I'm using Vue 3 with Vite for the front-end. I have a Vue component that I want to render inside a Twig template and pass some data to it from a Symfony controller, wheras the needed data is inside the template where the component lies in, which comes from the controller that is linked to the specific route.

In my current setup, I am able to bind my vue 3 components, that are stored under /assets/vue, to an app div with id 'app', so I can see it when I just add the native dom to the twig template:

```
<div>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is, that I want to pass data as props to this component and I am not sure how I can manage this using Smyfony's Controller and Twig as Template, where I bind in my component.

I tried to use it like this (as you see below), but I am not able to use the component write style inside my template as it is only 'html' so I am not able to pass props:

```
<div>
    <div id="app">
        <my-component :example-prop={{dataFromController}}></my-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

What approach could I use, so I can normally pass data from my controller to the Twig where my component lies so I can pass them as props? I didn't manage to use my custom vue component as component inside my app div too. What did I miss?

Here's what I have so far:

This is my index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello VueController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div>
    <div id="app">
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is my base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ vite_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ vite_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my ModeSwitcher.vue

```
<template>
  <div ref="themeToggleBtn" @click="console.log('clicked')">
    <button>Hello</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
```

this is my App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import BaseLayout from "./layout/BaseLayout.vue";
import StickyBanner from "./patterns/StickyBanner.vue";

</script>
<template>
  <BaseLayout>
    <template #header>
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <StickyBanner />
    </template>
    <template #main>
      <h1>Main</h1>
    </template>
    <template #footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </template>
  </BaseLayout>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

this is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import symfonyPlugin from "vite-plugin-symfony";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
/* if you're using React */
// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        /* react(), // if you're using React */
        symfonyPlugin(),
        vue(), // write this
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                app: "./assets/app.ts",
                /* you can also provide css files to prevent FOUC */
                styles: "./assets/styles/app.css"
            },
        }
    },
});
```

this is my app.ts

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main TS file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import './styles/app.css';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';

import {createApp} from "vue";
import App from "./vue/App.vue";
import ModeSwitcher from "./vue/patterns/ModeSwitcher.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
app.component('ModeSwitcher', ModeSwitcher);
```

my folder structure:
[image: root dir]

what I see inside my browser:
[image: browser]

Comment: "I am not able to use the component write style inside my template as it is only 'html'" - you actually can, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app . You need to have my-component component registered and use full Vue build

Comment: Did you read my post? I don't think so

Comment: I did. My assumption is that you missed the obvious solution for your problem, which is to pass data to the app through inline template, which is supported in Vue